# How to loop through an std::vector in repeating cycles

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I am using an `std::vector` with `C++` to store some items & retrieve them later. Following is how I am iterating through my vector.

```
std::vector<some_object> some_vector;
some_vector.resize(10);

for (auto it = some_vector.begin(); it != some_vector.end(); ++it) {
  int current_it_index = std::distance(some_vector.begin(), it);
}
```

I need the index per iteration. So, fetching it per iteration as demonstrated above.

Above loop *works well* but I **want to loop through the vector in infinite cycles**. How can I do that?

Now, I understand that the question comes, How do you stop the running loop if you let it run in repeating cycles. I am thinking to use an `std::atomic<bool>` as a variable to signal & break out of the loop which should work pretty well?

**PS:** Do note that I have taken `std::vector` as an example container to explain the question. It would be great if the suggested solution could work on `std::array` or other containers as well.

Comment: A simple `while` loop would do the trick. Don't overthink it, just wrap your current `for` loop into a `while` loop which will check the `std::atomic<bool>`. However it could be done using only the `for` loop you already have, you just need to change two things: 1) Reset the iterator at the end, 2) check the `std::atomic<bool>` you mentioned in order to know when to stop.

Comment: Do you want `current_it_index` to reset back to `0` after it starts to go through the vector again or should it keep increasing?  Also this kind of sounds like an XY problem.  If you tell us why you're doing this we might be able to point you to something different.

Comment: Got it. `for (auto it = some_vector.begin() ; ; ++it) {
  int current_it_index = std::distance(some_vector.begin(), it); if (it == some_vector.end() -1) it = some_vector.begin();
}`

Comment: thanks guys. got it. was too simple. yes, I overthought it

Comment: The answer you put in your comment has an off-by-one error.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes. it should be `it++` instead of `++it`. I think thats the error you pointing at?

Comment: No, your solution would skip over `begin()` after the first cycle.

Comment: aahh yessss ! I will fix that. superb :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<some_object> some_vector;
some_vector.resize(10);
bool quit = false;
while (!quit) {
  for (auto& e:some_vector) {
    if (quit) break;
    std::size_t i = std::addressof(e)-some_vector.data();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A common trick to iterating through an array that has a power of 2 number of elements is to simply iterate a counter and use a mask operation.

```
size_t counter = 0;
const size_t mask = some_vector.size() - 1U;

while (!quit) {
    size_t i = counter++ & mask;
    do_something(some_vector[i]);
}
```

If the array is not a power of two, you could perform modulo arithmetic instead of masking a free running counter.

```
size_t i = 0;
const size_t n = some_vector.size();

while (!quit) {
    do_something(some_vector[i++]);
    i %= n;
}
```

If you are using a non-random access container, and need iterators and indexes, then you could implement two loops. This would avoid the expense of computing `distance` on a non-random access iterator.

```
for (;;) {
    size_t idx = 0;
    for (auto it = some_container.begin();
         it != some_container.end();
         ++it) {
        do_something(it, idx++);
     }
```

Comment: This gets an index instead of an iterator, which might work for `vector` but doesn’t work for `list` or any other non-contiguous data structure.

Comment: Fair enough; my comment was imprecise. It was not in essence incorrect; this doesn’t work without an `operator[]`, `at()`, or other method of turning a `size_t` into an element.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want is that when you get to the last element of your container, you simply jump to the beginning of the container again. We can code that easily enough:

```
auto first = std::begin(c);
const auto last = std::end(c);
std::size_t idx = 0;

while (!should_exit()) {
    do_something(idx);

    ++idx;
    if (++first == last) { // reset
        idx = 0;
        first = std::begin(c);
    }
}
```

This should work for any STL-style container. Having both the iterator and the index is perhaps unnecessary, but this is a KISS solution that will work for non-random-access containers like `std::list` as well as vector/array.

Comment: In general this code has a dangerous reliance that do_something() doesn't invalidate iterators (or modify the container.)